# if xldate < 0.00: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' when read using xldate

Tags: python

when I am trying to read date in column 0 using the code below, I get an error as given below. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('call.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    for c in range(sheet.ncols):
        if c==0:
            a1=sheet.cell_value(r,0)
      a1_as_date=datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1,wb.datemode))
            print(a1_as_date)
        else:
            print(sheet.cell_value(r,c))
```

```
error
 a1_as_date=datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1,wb.datemode))
  File "C:\Users\user78\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 95, in xldate_as_tuple
    if xldate < 0.00:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you received an error that < is not supported by the two types.

I think you can try this out:

```
if float(xldate) < 0.00:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the value that should be converted is float:

```
  if isinstance(a1, float):
    a1_as_date = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, wb.datemode))
    
  else:
    a1_as_date = ''  # or any other empty value
```